# iOS 7+ Is there a possibility to capture video from frontal camera while showing another video on the screen?

Tags: ios, video, camera, capture

I have a task.
There is iOS device. There is an app I should create.
The app shows some video file (local video file from the device) while frontal camera captures users' face.
Showing video and capturing user's face via frontal camera are simultaneous.

I see that FaceTime and Skype for iOS can do this. But the former one created by Apple (they can do whatever on their devices) while latter one is owned by Microsoft (big companies/big money sometimes allowed more than usual developers).

Moreover, I doubt on co-existense of video capturing along with video player at the same time.
So, I am not sure that this task is 100% implement-able and publish-able.

Is it possible on iOS 7+?
Is it allowed by Apple to do this (I mean that there are many technical possibilities on iOS but only some of them are OK for Apple. Especially during moderation process)?
Are there good technical references?

Answer (score 0):

I believe so. Doing a search on Appstore shows a number of video conferencing apps:

- Zoom cloud
- Polycom
- VidyoMobile
- Fuze

Just search for "video conferencing".